# BLL log in validation c#

Tags: c#, wpf, business-logic-layer

So my question is: Does my BLL validate my log-in, or do i put the validation on the form UI?
Piece of code from my UI down below.

If so validated in the BLL layer, how do i do so?

```
private void ValidateForm(string username, string password)
        {
            var countdb = BLL.UsersBLL.VerifyDataBase();
            if (countdb >= 1)
            {
                var userdata = BLL.UsersBLL.VerifyUserData(username, password);

                if (userdata == 1)
                {
                    Entity.UsersEntity.UserSession.username = username;
                    var mainwindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
                    main main = new main();
                    mainwindow.Close();
                    main.Show();
                    main.username.Content = Entity.UsersEntity.UserSession.username;
                }
                else if (userdata <= 0)
                {
                    ErrorHandle.Content = "Verifique o usuário ou a senha.";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("O seu banco de dados está vazio! Por favor registrar um usuário.");
                register register = new register();
                register.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Programs do what you want them to do, and you write them the way you want to write them. There are no set rules per-se. So this question asks, how would you do validation for a login. Well it would depend on how big this application is, sure your libraries should validate everything, and they should validate their own inputs. However what your libraries return is sometimes vastly different than what a user might want to see. For something as simple as a failed login, true or false would be fine, as this is not exceptional, you would then tailor a message for your UI

Answer (score 1):

Move not UI related logic into dedicated business logic type

```
public class UserLogin
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class VerifyUserResult
{
    public static VerifyUserResult Success() => new VerifyUserResult();
    public static VerifyUserResult Fail(string message) => new VerifyUserResult(message);
    public string Message { get; }
    public bool Success => string.IsNullOrEmpty(Message);
  
    private VerifyUserResult(string message) => Message = message;
}

public class VerifyUser
{
    public VerifyUserResult Invoke(UserLogin user)
    {
        if (BLL.UsersBLL.VerifyDataBase() < 1)
        {
            return VerifyUserResult.Fail("Some message");
        }

        if (BLL.UsersBLL.VerifyUserData(username, password) != 1)
        {
            return VerifyUserResult.Fail("Another message");
        }

        return VerifyUserResult.Success();
    }
}
```

Then in UI code you just call it and make next decision based on the result